# How can I do Performance & Load Testing for Spring @Scheduled task

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jmeter, performance-testing

I want to run Performance & Load Test for a Spring @Scheduled task using Apache JMeter if possible.

1. Does it support this ?
2. And how can I achieve it ?

*I'm using Spring 5 (non boot) and JMeter 5.4.1*

Thank you

Edit 1:
My scheduled task is configured as below

```
package com.mypackage.impl;

import com.mypackage.service.NotificationBatchService;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@Service
@Transactional
public class NotificationBatchServiceImpl implements NotificationBatchService {

    @Override
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 */2 * * *")
    public void synchronizeNotificationUploadDocument() {
        // database transactions
        // HTTP requests
    }
}
```

Comment: How your scheduler defined? If it happens once an hour or more, why you need execute load test on it? Can you test endpoint calling same method?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've added the configuration to the original post. 
Our need is to invoke it from JMeter but I have no idea how I can do it

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the code inside of the method `synchronizeNotificationUploadDocument` to a service and then load test this service.